# move turtles and create a crowd to target

Tags: netlogo

```
to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  ask patches [
    set inside? (abs pycor < 10 and abs pxcor < 10)       
    set exit? false
    ask patch 11 0 [ set pcolor lime set exit? true]
  ]

  repeat initial-population [ ; start condition turtles with any other turtles on neighbors 
    ask one-of patches with [
      inside? and (not any? other turtles-here) and (not any? turtles-on neighbors)] [
      sprout 1 [
        set color blue
        set size 1
      ]]]  
end

to go  
  tick
  define-neighbors-radius-2
  move  
end

to define-neighbors-radius-2
   ask turtles [     
    set neighbors-ahead2 patches at-points [[2 1] [2 0] [2 -1]] 
    set neighbors-for-y-up2 patches at-points [[2 0] [2 -1] [1 -2] [0 -2] [-1 -2]] with [inside?]
    set neighbors-for-y-down2 patches at-points [[-1 2] [0 2] [1 2] [2 1] [2 0]] with [inside?]  
  ]
end

to move  
;; my intent to move turtles to exit without their neighbors are occupied by other turtles,          ;;that is the 8 patches around turtles are empty until exit?  

ask turtles[
    ifelse inside? [
      if ycor = 0 [    ;strategy to turtles with in front exit
        ifelse exit? [
          set heading 90 
          fd .5
        ]
        [
          facexy 11 0
          if (not any? turtles-on neighbors) and (not any? turtles-on neighbors-ahead2) [
            fd .5
          ]
        ]
      ]
      if ycor > 0 [     ; strategy to turtles occupied "bottom-side" of inside?
        facexy 11 0
        if (not any? turtles-on neighbors) and (not any? turtles-on neighbors-for-y-up2) [
          fd .5
        ]
      ]
      if ycor < 0 [      ; strategy to turtles occupied "down-side" of inside?
        facexy 11 0
        if (not any? turtles-on neighbors) and (not any? turtles-on neighbors-for-y-down2) [
          fd .5
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [
      set heading 90 
      fd .5
    ]
  ]  
end
```

I try to move turtles to exit but not all turtles move, why?
also, turtles must go out with ycor = 0, that is obliques direction don't allow because neighbors will occupied patches aren't inside! 
Can't public this question because "looks like my post is mostly code", so talk about of my life: 
seriously my intent is to create a crowd in front of exit and set some rules to delay the turtles flow exit, for this I need the neighbors empty to show interaction between agents.
(also accept some suggest to set this interaction) but at the moment turtles reach exit!
thanks

Comment: "also, turtles must go out with ycor = 0, that is obliques direction don't allow because neighbors will occupied patches aren't inside" — cannot make any sense of this sentence

Comment: sorry english language isn't my quality.

Comment: turtles go exit from patch 10 0, patch at the same pycor of exit, so ycor = 0, and not from patch 10 1 or 10 -1 like in the code example.

Comment: You can edit your original question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with this code is that have you three `if`s where it appears you only want one of them to run each time, but it's possible for more than one of them to trigger. You have:

```
if ycor = 0 [ ...commands #1... ]
if ycor > 0 [ ...commands #2... ]
if ycor < 0 [ ...commands #3... ]
```

but the turtle's `ycor` might be changed by commands #1 or #2.  So it's possible that both #1 and #2 might run, or both #2 and #3, and perhaps other combinations as well. I assume you intended that each turtle should only move once per tick, so I recommend you rewrite this as:

```
ifelse ycor = 0
  [ ...commands #1... ]
  [ ifelse ycor > 0
      [ ...commands #2... ]
      [ ...commands #3... ] ]
```

Something else that should be fixed in this code:

- `reset-ticks` should go at the end of `setup`, not near the start. It tells NetLogo setup is finished.
- `tick` should go at the end of `go`, not near the start. It tells NetLogo a tick has finished.

I don't know if either of these problems I've pointed out are actually causing the unintended behavior you're seeing. Perhaps the bug isn't obvious just from reading over the code. In that case, you have two possible courses of action ahead of you:

1) Back up. Throw away this broken code and go back to the last version of your model that contained only code that have you have verified to work correctly. Then try again, but this time, don't add so much new code all at once. Attempt to make a very small improvement to the code, and get that working, before moving on to the next small improvement. And so on. If at any point you get stuck, come here, show your code, and ask a specific question about it. That question should be much easier to answer than your current question. Questions of the form “Here is a big mass of code that doesn't work, help!" are very difficult to answer.

2) Press on by investigating your questions yourself. You write, “not all turtles move, why?”  Perhaps someone can answer this just by reading your code; I can't (unless my first guess above is correct).  In order to figure it out, I would have to run the code myself and do experiments with it. I'd do things like try running it with just a single turtle and see if that case fails; add `print` statements to the code, showing each the turtle's coordinates and motions, so I could try and figure out which turtle is going wrong, and exactly under what conditions; and so forth. It's like detective work, or like doing chemistry experiments in the lab.

Comment: can i use function arcsin in netlogo? how can i write it?

Comment: Please open a new question to ask that.

Comment: I can't do this kind of question. stack overflow rules'..i don't know